# Is it better to do calculations in SQL stored procedure or program

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, performance, stored-procedures

I am an intern at a company and myself and my fellow interns are tasked with creating a reporting dashboard. We are using MVC, an API and SQL Server .

Currently we are getting data for the dashboard using 9 different stored procedures. These stored procedures do some calculations using aggregate functions (ie how many sales someone made among other things) and are filtered according to a date range (as well as some other filters like products). One stored proc result set, in general, returns about 100 to 200 rows, calculated from about 70 000 rows of raw data in the database - if the date range filter is set to one month. So we land up getting about 9 tables with 100-200 rows each to populate our dashboard

Our problem is that a user may change the various filters, which currently requires us to get all nine results sets from the database again, and is currently a little slow - it takes about 15 seconds to refresh or more

One of the interns in my team wants to change the code so that all the data is called from the database in a raw format (ie the 70 000 rows in the database for each stored proc) without filtering, and then apply user filters and the calculations in C#. Of course this takes out the date range filters which means all data in the databsae will be returned, so instead of 70 000 rows each stored proc would return about 2 520 000 rows, since the database is about 3 years old... and of course the total number of rows will increase each month.

I have no idea if this is a good idea... I don't know if it will increase performance or not. So I basically have two main questions:

1. Will c# be able to run those calculations (how many sales a person has made) faster and more efficiently  than SQL
2. Will having 9 tables with roughly 2.5 million rows of data (and counting) each called to the front end not cause everything to slow down anyway, making any benefits null and void

Another suggestion was to invest time in improving the stored procs themselves, and change the front end to call those stored procs in parallel instead in sequence, which is what we do now.

***ANSWER:***
Alright so after reading all responses the way forward would seem to be to fix those stored procs and improve their performance. While c# might possibly do calculations faster it in no way makes up for the resources required to move the data and store it, and those stored procs should not be as slow as they are anyway.

We could potentially do it with c# with filters included but doing it in SQL seems to be better.

***is there a way I can select everyone's input as the answer?***

Comment: A well-tuned C# program might do calculations faster than SQL engine, specially if you distribute work accross threads, but the problem then becomes the resources spent moving the data that C# needs from the database to memory (and storing the result on the way back, if needed). The SQL engine also uses their sql magic (indexes and statistics) to optimize the selecting stage of rows, something that might not be bested in your C# app (if you want to filter and not just do calculations).

Comment: Its not a good idea to remove filters

Comment: The question you should be asking first is why the queries are slow. Aggregating 70K rows should not take 15 seconds, nor should selecting 70K rows from a mere 2.5M. Which one is the bottleneck? First, determine if the selection of 70K from 2.5M is your bottleneck or the aggregation. If the selection is slow, ensure that you are using available indices properly; if not, ensure that the required indices are available on the table(s). If it is only the aggregation which is slow, perhaps something is wrong in how it is stated. As a fallback, get 70K rows and aggregate in C#; but filter in the DB.

Comment: Is it possible to test getting all the data back - it may add a completely unacceptable delay at the start of the application. Also, do you ever need current information - in which case you would either need more stored procedures to get the latest data or retrieve the entire 20 odd million records again.

Comment: There is no single way to answer this question, as there are arguments for both ways. I find it really hard to do proper unit-testing when lots of functionality is only implemented as SQL and SQL Functions/Procedures but if you can manage that part I'd definitely consider it. However, you might also be able to implement calculations more efficiently in C# as SQL is inherently finicky about complex data structures and imperative logic, in our product we have calculations we cannot get efficient implementations of in SQL without sort of inventing a new programming language for it. So +/-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to do calculations with stored procedures. It saves time.make sure all the calculations are not done in one stored procedure. You can create different procedures and have one final procedure to combine all the stored procedures. Moreover you can use functions as well.make use of the properties of sql server to your advantage. Stored procedures will be faster than doing the calculations in c#. Make sure you set the timeout time when calling the stored procedure in c#. Its very helpful or else you won't get the expected results.